# Android animated GIF (Cupcake)

Tags: android, animated-gif, android-1.5-cupcake

I've used animated GIFs in Android pre cupcake however my old code no longer works. To be exact:

```
Movie.decodeStream
```

Always returns null... Does anyone have any workarounds/fixes to play animated GIFs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [a bug report for this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2766). Looks like the only option currently is to split it up and do frame-by-frame animation manually. There's [instructions in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation) for how to do this.