# how to play animated gif file in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to play GIF format in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163706/is-it-possible-to-play-gif-format-in-android)

can anyone please tell me how i show animated .gif file in android.

thanks in adv..

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163706/is-it-possible-to-play-gif-format-in-android

Answer (score 0):

however android don,t support gif.so first,extract all frames of gif image using tool gifExtracter.Then you can use frame animation to display gif.