# use gif images for loading screen in android

Tags: android

In my android i am using progress dialog for showing loading screen but is it possible to use gif images.
Could any one please let me know how to use gif images for loading.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android: How do a display a large animated gif given a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809878/android-how-do-a-display-a-large-animated-gif-given-a-url)

And checkout the BitmapDecode given in APIDemos.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Android doesn't support GIF images' animation, so you'll perhaps have to try the other way around: create separate images for each state of your current GIF, and animate them using Android 2D animation.

This is manual, and time consuming, but sadly this is what I can suggest.