# Why are .gif animated images not animating in my Android app?

Tags: android, image, animation, animated-gif

I'm trying to use .gif animated images in my app, but the image is not animating.  On an iPhone it works...  why is Android blocking the animation?  Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like plenty of people are wanting animated GIFs to just work on Android, but they don't currently - see [Issue 3422 on the Android bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422).

It looks like you may be able to do it by treating the animated GIF as a movie according to http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.com/2010/09/gif-animation-in-android.html

Similar question, which has an answer which may help you: [Android: How do a display a large animated gif given a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809878/android-how-do-a-display-a-large-animated-gif-given-a-url)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

here is sample code.

**GIFDemo1.java**

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class GIFDemo1 extends GraphicsActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new GIFView(this));
    }
    private static class GIFView extends View{

        Movie movie,movie1;
        InputStream is=null,is1=null;
        long moviestart;
        long moviestart1;
        public GIFView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.cartoon);
            is1=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.animated_gif);
            movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
            movie1=Movie.decodeStream(is1);
            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;    // this will request the bm
            opts.inSampleSize = 10;   
            //movie=Movie.decodeFile("C:\\cartoon.gif");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            System.out.println("now="+now);
             if (moviestart == 0) {   // first time
                 moviestart = now;

             }
             if(moviestart1==0)
             {
                 moviestart1=now;
             }
             System.out.println("\tmoviestart="+moviestart);
             int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration()) ;
             int relTime1=(int)((now - moviestart1)% movie1.duration());
             System.out.println("time="+relTime+"\treltime="+movie.duration());
             movie.setTime(relTime);
             movie1.setTime(relTime1);
             movie.draw(canvas,10,10);
             movie1.draw(canvas,10,100);
             this.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

**GraphicsActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class GraphicsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        if (false) { 
            // set to true to test Picture
            ViewGroup vg = new PictureLayout(this);
            vg.addView(view);
            view = vg;
        }

        super.setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

**PictureLayout.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;

public class PictureLayout extends ViewGroup {
    private final Picture mPicture = new Picture();

    public PictureLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PictureLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }    

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        if (getChildCount() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("PictureLayout can host only one direct child");
        }

        super.addView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index) {
        if (getChildCount() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("PictureLayout can host only one direct child");
        }

        super.addView(child, index);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, LayoutParams params) {
        if (getChildCount() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("PictureLayout can host only one direct child");
        }

        super.addView(child, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params) {
        if (getChildCount() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("PictureLayout can host only one direct child");
        }

        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int count = getChildCount();

        int maxHeight = 0;
        int maxWidth = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }

        maxWidth += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        maxHeight += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        Drawable drawable = getBackground();
        if (drawable != null) {
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, drawable.getMinimumHeight());
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, drawable.getMinimumWidth());
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(maxWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
                resolveSize(maxHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    private void drawPict(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int w, int h,
                          float sx, float sy) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(x, y);
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, w, h);
        canvas.scale(0.5f, 0.5f);
        canvas.scale(sx, sy, w, h);
        canvas.drawPicture(mPicture);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(mPicture.beginRecording(getWidth(), getHeight()));
        mPicture.endRecording();

        int x = getWidth()/2;
        int y = getHeight()/2;

        if (false) {
            canvas.drawPicture(mPicture);
        } else {
            drawPict(canvas, 0, 0, x, y,  1,  1);
            drawPict(canvas, x, 0, x, y, -1,  1);
            drawPict(canvas, 0, y, x, y,  1, -1);
            drawPict(canvas, x, y, x, y, -1, -1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewParent invalidateChildInParent(int[] location, Rect dirty) {
        location[0] = getLeft();
        location[1] = getTop();
        dirty.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        return getParent();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int count = super.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                final int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
                final int childTop = getPaddingTop();
                child.layout(childLeft, childTop,
                        childLeft + child.getMeasuredWidth(),
                        childTop + child.getMeasuredHeight());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

hope this help you.
it not work for very complex gif.