# my gif images are shown in emulator but are missing in my smart phone

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

in my application i am displaying a few gif images which workd perfectly in emulator but when i install the apk file in my smartphone the application works as normal but gif images are not displayed , any explanation why ??

here is my code for the view for gif display

```
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;

public class GifWebView extends View {
    private Movie mMovie;
    InputStream mStream;
    long mMoviestart;

    public GifWebView(Context context, InputStream stream) {
        super(context);
        mStream = stream;
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mStream);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (mMoviestart == 0) 
        {
            mMoviestart = now;
        }
        int gif_image_duration = mMovie.duration();
        if(gif_image_duration==0)
        {
            gif_image_duration = 1;
        }
        final int relTime = (int) ((now - mMoviestart) % gif_image_duration);
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

and in my activity i call

```
GifWebView gif_view;// as global var
```

and in my on create method

```
    gif_linear_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.gif_linear_layout);
InputStream stream = null;
            try {
                stream = getAssets().open(gif_name);
                //stream = getAssets().open("gif_images").;
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            gif_view = new GifWebView(this, stream);
            gif_linear_layout.addView(gif_view);
```

this is how it looks like part 1 : on emulator part 2 : on my smart phon [image]

[image]

Comment: maybe the emulator shows from cache, try to uninstall from emulator too, than check again. Use png usually is better, if GIF has some animation , other stuff some libraryes are producing error effects

Comment: yeah , did that , same thing , emulator works but on the phon it doesn't

Comment: This might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: Using gif format image seems to be discouraged. Check this. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/SuBm1kAuAMw

Comment: @NitinSethi : it's kind of a requirement , cant change it

Comment: is your gif animated?

Comment: @matheszabi : yes gifs are animated

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid than Google: "Android how to present animated gif on UI" Probably a custom library can handle, but by default the Android ( 2.3.3 at least) can't

Comment: As noted elsewhere, animated GIFs are not well supported in Android. If these images are packaged in your app, consider using this script that I wrote to convert them to `AnimationDrawable`s: https://gist.github.com/commonsguy/6757059

Comment: @CommonsWare : i'try that right away , but my main curiosity is , IF GIF IMAGES ARE NOT WELL SUPPORTED IN ANDROID , HOW COME I HAVE THEM DISPLAY PROPERLY IN MY EMULATOR ?

Comment: Maybe this helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12732576/1917237 EDIT and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6534076/1917237 EDIT AGAIN http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/

Comment: Could you upload your gif animation to dropbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was face the same problem. If you are confident your code is ok, then just add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in your manifest of your this activity. Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is works like charm with me:

**GifView.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class GifView extends View {

    public static final int IMAGE_TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0;
    public static final int IMAGE_TYPE_STATIC = 1;
    public static final int IMAGE_TYPE_DYNAMIC = 2;

    public static final int DECODE_STATUS_UNDECODE = 0;
    public static final int DECODE_STATUS_DECODING = 1;
    public static final int DECODE_STATUS_DECODED = 2;

    private GifDecoder decoder;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public int imageType = IMAGE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
    public int decodeStatus = DECODE_STATUS_UNDECODE;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    private long time;
    private int index;

    private int resId;
    private String filePath;

    private boolean playFlag = false;

    int gifImageResourceID;

    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        String namespace = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/" + context.getPackageName();
        gifImageResourceID = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(namespace, "gif_image", 0);

        if (gifImageResourceID != 0) {
            setGifImageResourceID(gifImageResourceID);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public GifView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    private InputStream getInputStream() {
        if (filePath != null)
            try {
                return new FileInputStream(filePath);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            }
        if (resId > 0)
            return getContext().getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * set gif file path
     *
     * @param filePath
     */
    public void setGif(String filePath) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        setGif(filePath, bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (bitmap != null) {
            setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(bitmap.getWidth()), MeasureSpec.getSize(bitmap.getHeight()));
        }

    }



    /**
     * set gif file path and cache image
     *
     * @param filePath
     * @param cacheImage
     */
    public void setGif(String filePath, Bitmap cacheImage) {
        this.resId = 0;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        imageType = IMAGE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
        decodeStatus = DECODE_STATUS_UNDECODE;
        playFlag = false;
        bitmap = cacheImage;
        width = bitmap.getWidth();
        height = bitmap.getHeight();
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        setLayoutParams(params);
        play();
    }

    /**
     * set gif resource id
     *
     * @param resId
     */

    public void setGifImageResourceID(int resId) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
        setGif(resId, bitmap);
    }

    /**
     * set gif resource id and cache image
     *
     * @param resId
     * @param cacheImage
     */
    public void setGif(int resId, Bitmap cacheImage) {
        this.filePath = null;
        this.resId = resId;
        imageType = IMAGE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
        decodeStatus = DECODE_STATUS_UNDECODE;
        playFlag = false;
        bitmap = cacheImage;
        width = bitmap.getWidth();
        height = bitmap.getHeight();
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
        play();
    }

    private void decode() {
        release();
        index = 0;

        decodeStatus = DECODE_STATUS_DECODING;

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                decoder = new GifDecoder();
                decoder.read(getInputStream());
                if (decoder.width == 0 || decoder.height == 0) {
                    imageType = IMAGE_TYPE_STATIC;
                } else {
                    imageType = IMAGE_TYPE_DYNAMIC;
                }
                postInvalidate();
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                decodeStatus = DECODE_STATUS_DECODED;
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void release() {
        decoder = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (decodeStatus == DECODE_STATUS_UNDECODE) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (getWidth()-width)/2, (getHeight()-height)/2, null);
            if (playFlag) {
                decode();
                invalidate();
            }
        } else if (decodeStatus == DECODE_STATUS_DECODING) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (getWidth()-width)/2, (getHeight()-height)/2, null);
            invalidate();
        } else if (decodeStatus == DECODE_STATUS_DECODED) {
            if (imageType == IMAGE_TYPE_STATIC) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (getWidth()-width)/2, (getHeight()-height)/2, null);
            } else if (imageType == IMAGE_TYPE_DYNAMIC) {
                if (playFlag) {
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if (time + decoder.getDelay(index) < now) {
                        time += decoder.getDelay(index);
                        incrementFrameIndex();
                    }
                    Bitmap bitmap = decoder.getFrame(index);
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (getWidth()-width)/2, (getHeight()-height)/2, null);
                    }
                    invalidate();
                } else {
                    Bitmap bitmap = decoder.getFrame(index);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (getWidth()-width)/2, (getHeight()-height)/2, null);
                }
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (getWidth()-width)/2, (getHeight()-height)/2, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void incrementFrameIndex() {
        index++;
        if (index >= decoder.getFrameCount()) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    private void decrementFrameIndex() {
        index--;
        if (index < 0) {
            index = decoder.getFrameCount() - 1;
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        playFlag = true;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void pause() {
        playFlag = false;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void stop() {
        playFlag = false;
        index = 0;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void nextFrame() {
        if (decodeStatus == DECODE_STATUS_DECODED) {
            incrementFrameIndex();
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void prevFrame() {
        if (decodeStatus == DECODE_STATUS_DECODED) {
            decrementFrameIndex();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

**GifDecoder.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;

public class GifDecoder {
    /**
     * File read status: No errors.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;
    /**
     * File read status: Error decoding file (may be partially decoded)
     */
    public static final int STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR = 1;
    /**
     * File read status: Unable to open source.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_OPEN_ERROR = 2;
    /** max decoder pixel stack size */
    protected static final int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 4096;
    protected InputStream in;
    protected int status;
    protected int width; // full image width
    protected int height; // full image height
    protected boolean gctFlag; // global color table used
    protected int gctSize; // size of global color table
    protected int loopCount = 1; // iterations; 0 = repeat forever
    protected int[] gct; // global color table
    protected int[] lct; // local color table
    protected int[] act; // active color table
    protected int bgIndex; // background color index
    protected int bgColor; // background color
    protected int lastBgColor; // previous bg color
    protected int pixelAspect; // pixel aspect ratio
    protected boolean lctFlag; // local color table flag
    protected boolean interlace; // interlace flag
    protected int lctSize; // local color table size
    protected int ix, iy, iw, ih; // current image rectangle
    protected int lrx, lry, lrw, lrh;
    protected Bitmap image; // current frame
    protected Bitmap lastBitmap; // previous frame
    protected byte[] block = new byte[256]; // current data block
    protected int blockSize = 0; // block size last graphic control extension info
    protected int dispose = 0; // 0=no action; 1=leave in place; 2=restore to bg; 3=restore to prev
    protected int lastDispose = 0;
    protected boolean transparency = false; // use transparent color
    protected int delay = 0; // delay in milliseconds
    protected int transIndex; // transparent color index
    // LZW decoder working arrays
    protected short[] prefix;
    protected byte[] suffix;
    protected byte[] pixelStack;
    protected byte[] pixels;
    protected Vector<GifFrame> frames; // frames read from current file
    protected int frameCount;

    private static class GifFrame {
        public GifFrame(Bitmap im, int del) {
            image = im;
            delay = del;
        }

        public Bitmap image;
        public int delay;
    }

    /**
     * Gets display duration for specified frame.
     * 
     * @param n
     *          int index of frame
     * @return delay in milliseconds
     */
    public int getDelay(int n) {
        delay = -1;
        if ((n >= 0) && (n < frameCount)) {
            delay = frames.elementAt(n).delay;
        }
        return delay;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of frames read from file.
     * 
     * @return frame count
     */
    public int getFrameCount() {
        return frameCount;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the first (or only) image read.
     * 
     * @return BufferedBitmap containing first frame, or null if none.
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return getFrame(0);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the "Netscape" iteration count, if any. A count of 0 means repeat indefinitiely.
     * 
     * @return iteration count if one was specified, else 1.
     */
    public int getLoopCount() {
        return loopCount;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new frame image from current data (and previous frames as specified by their disposition codes).
     */
    protected void setPixels() {
        // expose destination image's pixels as int array
        int[] dest = new int[width * height];
        // fill in starting image contents based on last image's dispose code
        if (lastDispose > 0) {
            if (lastDispose == 3) {
                // use image before last
                int n = frameCount - 2;
                if (n > 0) {
                    lastBitmap = getFrame(n - 1);
                } else {
                    lastBitmap = null;
                }
            }
            if (lastBitmap != null) {
                lastBitmap.getPixels(dest, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                // copy pixels
                if (lastDispose == 2) {
                    // fill last image rect area with background color
                    int c = 0;
                    if (!transparency) {
                        c = lastBgColor;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < lrh; i++) {
                        int n1 = (lry + i) * width + lrx;
                        int n2 = n1 + lrw;
                        for (int k = n1; k < n2; k++) {
                            dest[k] = c;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // copy each source line to the appropriate place in the destination
        int pass = 1;
        int inc = 8;
        int iline = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ih; i++) {
            int line = i;
            if (interlace) {
                if (iline >= ih) {
                    pass++;
                    switch (pass) {
                    case 2:
                        iline = 4;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        iline = 2;
                        inc = 4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        iline = 1;
                        inc = 2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                line = iline;
                iline += inc;
            }
            line += iy;
            if (line < height) {
                int k = line * width;
                int dx = k + ix; // start of line in dest
                int dlim = dx + iw; // end of dest line
                if ((k + width) < dlim) {
                    dlim = k + width; // past dest edge
                }
                int sx = i * iw; // start of line in source
                while (dx < dlim) {
                    // map color and insert in destination
                    int index = ((int) pixels[sx++]) & 0xff;
                    int c = act[index];
                    if (c != 0) {
                        dest[dx] = c;
                    }
                    dx++;
                }
            }
        }
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest, width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the image contents of frame n.
     * 
     * @return BufferedBitmap representation of frame, or null if n is invalid.
     */
    public Bitmap getFrame(int n) {
        if (frameCount <= 0)
            return null;
        n = n % frameCount;
        return ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(n)).image;
    }

    /**
     * Reads GIF image from stream
     * 
     * @param is
     *          containing GIF file.
     * @return read status code (0 = no errors)
     */
    public int read(InputStream is) {
        init();
        if (is != null) {
            in = is;
            readHeader();
            if (!err()) {
                readContents();
                if (frameCount < 0) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                }
            }
        } else {
            status = STATUS_OPEN_ERROR;
        }
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * Decodes LZW image data into pixel array. Adapted from John Cristy's BitmapMagick.
     */
    protected void decodeBitmapData() {
        int nullCode = -1;
        int npix = iw * ih;
        int available, clear, code_mask, code_size, end_of_information, in_code, old_code, bits, code, count, i, datum, data_size, first, top, bi, pi;
        if ((pixels == null) || (pixels.length < npix)) {
            pixels = new byte[npix]; // allocate new pixel array
        }
        if (prefix == null) {
            prefix = new short[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
        }
        if (suffix == null) {
            suffix = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
        }
        if (pixelStack == null) {
            pixelStack = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE + 1];
        }
        // Initialize GIF data stream decoder.
        data_size = read();
        clear = 1 << data_size;
        end_of_information = clear + 1;
        available = clear + 2;
        old_code = nullCode;
        code_size = data_size + 1;
        code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
        for (code = 0; code < clear; code++) {
            prefix[code] = 0; // XXX ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            suffix[code] = (byte) code;
        }
        // Decode GIF pixel stream.
        datum = bits = count = first = top = pi = bi = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < npix;) {
            if (top == 0) {
                if (bits < code_size) {
                    // Load bytes until there are enough bits for a code.
                    if (count == 0) {
                        // Read a new data block.
                        count = readBlock();
                        if (count <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        bi = 0;
                    }
                    datum += (((int) block[bi]) & 0xff) << bits;
                    bits += 8;
                    bi++;
                    count--;
                    continue;
                }
                // Get the next code.
                code = datum & code_mask;
                datum >>= code_size;
                bits -= code_size;
                // Interpret the code
                if ((code > available) || (code == end_of_information)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (code == clear) {
                    // Reset decoder.
                    code_size = data_size + 1;
                    code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
                    available = clear + 2;
                    old_code = nullCode;
                    continue;
                }
                if (old_code == nullCode) {
                    pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                    old_code = code;
                    first = code;
                    continue;
                }
                in_code = code;
                if (code == available) {
                    pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                    code = old_code;
                }
                while (code > clear) {
                    pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                    code = prefix[code];
                }
                first = ((int) suffix[code]) & 0xff;
                // Add a new string to the string table,
                if (available >= MAX_STACK_SIZE) {
                    break;
                }
                pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                prefix[available] = (short) old_code;
                suffix[available] = (byte) first;
                available++;
                if (((available & code_mask) == 0) && (available < MAX_STACK_SIZE)) {
                    code_size++;
                    code_mask += available;
                }
                old_code = in_code;
            }
            // Pop a pixel off the pixel stack.
            top--;
            pixels[pi++] = pixelStack[top];
            i++;
        }
        for (i = pi; i < npix; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0; // clear missing pixels
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if an error was encountered during reading/decoding
     */
    protected boolean err() {
        return status != STATUS_OK;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes or re-initializes reader
     */
    protected void init() {
        status = STATUS_OK;
        frameCount = 0;
        frames = new Vector<GifFrame>();
        gct = null;
        lct = null;
    }

    /**
     * Reads a single byte from the input stream.
     */
    protected int read() {
        int curByte = 0;
        try {
            curByte = in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        }
        return curByte;
    }

    /**
     * Reads next variable length block from input.
     * 
     * @return number of bytes stored in "buffer"
     */
    protected int readBlock() {
        blockSize = read();
        int n = 0;
        if (blockSize > 0) {
            try {
                int count = 0;
                while (n < blockSize) {
                    count = in.read(block, n, blockSize - n);
                    if (count == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    n += count;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (n < blockSize) {
                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    /**
     * Reads color table as 256 RGB integer values
     * 
     * @param ncolors
     *          int number of colors to read
     * @return int array containing 256 colors (packed ARGB with full alpha)
     */
    protected int[] readColorTable(int ncolors) {
        int nbytes = 3 * ncolors;
        int[] tab = null;
        byte[] c = new byte[nbytes];
        int n = 0;
        try {
            n = in.read(c);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (n < nbytes) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        } else {
            tab = new int[256]; // max size to avoid bounds checks
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (i < ncolors) {
                int r = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                int g = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                int b = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                tab[i++] = 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            }
        }
        return tab;
    }

    /**
     * Main file parser. Reads GIF content blocks.
     */
    protected void readContents() {
        // read GIF file content blocks
        boolean done = false;
        while (!(done || err())) {
            int code = read();
            switch (code) {
            case 0x2C: // image separator
                readBitmap();
                break;
            case 0x21: // extension
                code = read();
                switch (code) {
                case 0xf9: // graphics control extension
                    readGraphicControlExt();
                    break;
                case 0xff: // application extension
                    readBlock();
                    String app = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                        app += (char) block[i];
                    }
                    if (app.equals("NETSCAPE2.0")) {
                        readNetscapeExt();
                    } else {
                        skip(); // don't care
                    }
                    break;
                case 0xfe:// comment extension
                    skip();
                    break;
                case 0x01:// plain text extension
                    skip();
                    break;
                default: // uninteresting extension
                    skip();
                }
                break;
            case 0x3b: // terminator
                done = true;
                break;
            case 0x00: // bad byte, but keep going and see what happens break;
            default:
                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads Graphics Control Extension values
     */
    protected void readGraphicControlExt() {
        read(); // block size
        int packed = read(); // packed fields
        dispose = (packed & 0x1c) >> 2; // disposal method
        if (dispose == 0) {
            dispose = 1; // elect to keep old image if discretionary
        }
        transparency = (packed & 1) != 0;
        delay = readShort() * 10; // delay in milliseconds
        transIndex = read(); // transparent color index
        read(); // block terminator
    }

    /**
     * Reads GIF file header information.
     */
    protected void readHeader() {
        String id = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            id += (char) read();
        }
        if (!id.startsWith("GIF")) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            return;
        }
        readLSD();
        if (gctFlag && !err()) {
            gct = readColorTable(gctSize);
            bgColor = gct[bgIndex];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads next frame image
     */
    protected void readBitmap() {
        ix = readShort(); // (sub)image position & size
        iy = readShort();
        iw = readShort();
        ih = readShort();
        int packed = read();
        lctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 - local color table flag interlace
        lctSize = (int) Math.pow(2, (packed & 0x07) + 1);
        // 3 - sort flag
        // 4-5 - reserved lctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 - local color
        // table size
        interlace = (packed & 0x40) != 0;
        if (lctFlag) {
            lct = readColorTable(lctSize); // read table
            act = lct; // make local table active
        } else {
            act = gct; // make global table active
            if (bgIndex == transIndex) {
                bgColor = 0;
            }
        }
        int save = 0;
        if (transparency) {
            save = act[transIndex];
            act[transIndex] = 0; // set transparent color if specified
        }
        if (act == null) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR; // no color table defined
        }
        if (err()) {
            return;
        }
        decodeBitmapData(); // decode pixel data
        skip();
        if (err()) {
            return;
        }
        frameCount++;
        // create new image to receive frame data
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
        setPixels(); // transfer pixel data to image
        frames.addElement(new GifFrame(image, delay)); // add image to frame
        // list
        if (transparency) {
            act[transIndex] = save;
        }
        resetFrame();
    }

    /**
     * Reads Logical Screen Descriptor
     */
    protected void readLSD() {
        // logical screen size
        width = readShort();
        height = readShort();
        // packed fields
        int packed = read();
        gctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 : global color table flag
        // 2-4 : color resolution
        // 5 : gct sort flag
        gctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 : gct size
        bgIndex = read(); // background color index
        pixelAspect = read(); // pixel aspect ratio
    }

    /**
     * Reads Netscape extenstion to obtain iteration count
     */
    protected void readNetscapeExt() {
        do {
            readBlock();
            if (block[0] == 1) {
                // loop count sub-block
                int b1 = ((int) block[1]) & 0xff;
                int b2 = ((int) block[2]) & 0xff;
                loopCount = (b2 << 8) | b1;
            }
        } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }

    /**
     * Reads next 16-bit value, LSB first
     */
    protected int readShort() {
        // read 16-bit value, LSB first
        return read() | (read() << 8);
    }

    /**
     * Resets frame state for reading next image.
     */
    protected void resetFrame() {
        lastDispose = dispose;
        lrx = ix;
        lry = iy;
        lrw = iw;
        lrh = ih;
        lastBitmap = image;
        lastBgColor = bgColor;
        dispose = 0;
        transparency = false;
        delay = 0;
        lct = null;
    }

    /**
     * Skips variable length blocks up to and including next zero length block.
     */
    protected void skip() {
        do {
            readBlock();
        } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }
}
```

**How to use?**

put your all images in res/drawable folder rather asset folder.

```
    gif_view = new GifWebView(this);
    gif_view.setGifImageResourceID(R.drawable.apple);
    gif_linear_layout.addView(gif_view);
```

Comment: thanx man , cant test it right away , but will let you know in a few hours

Comment: ok bro this works great with me and it this "GifView" has ability to play gif image from sdcard also.

Comment: sounds great , i would sure the bounty doesnt gets wasted

Comment: Great!,is there anyway to play gif full screen?

Comment: i found! use canvas.scale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight); to make it fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

It will not solve your problem, but maybe gives a hint:

```
if(stream != null){
    gif_view = new GifWebView(this, stream);
}
else{
  Log.d("tag", "can't load gif image from assets");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Emulator's window dimension difference your smartphone maybe didn't show on your phone.

```
mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10); // change dimension value and find correct one.
```

Comment: the left arrow , the gif image linear layout and the right arrow image , they all are in a horizontal linear layout , so if it is dimension then the right arrow image should not be displayed

Comment: Could you check your canvas draw position? Is it in your showable area? I have experience before this thread and than change my movie draw area attribute. After I saw gif movie.

Comment: see the edit , have added another image , doont think its the position issue

Comment: Could you analyse AndroidSDK Samples? In ApiDemos under graphics tabs you will see BitmapDecode.java source. This movie draw method args --> mMovie.draw(canvas, <view>.getWidth() - mMovie.width(),
                            <view>.getHeight() - mMovie.height());

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshots, looks like both your emulator and phone are on Android 4+, but there is still a chance that the framework on your phone is missing an important commit that I mentioned in [my answer to another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090385/1023092). Maybe you can test your app on an emulator with Android 2.3.3 (API10) to see if it behaves the same on it as on your phone?

As for a more reliable solution, maybe you can try the library in the linked post or the other methods that were suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not natively display animated GIFs. However, you can resort to using the android.graphics.Movie class as explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif).

As explained briefly, the feature is lightly discussed in [SDK Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html), but used in [Samples in ApiDemos in BitmapDecode](https://code.google.com/p/apidemos/source/browse/trunk/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapDecode.java#103).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

place the image in drawable folder and then check for your information android does not support gif animation it will only display one frame only

Comment: first thing : i did try with images in drawable folder , same case . Second thing : if android does not support then how come the emulator shows it , it also has android only right ??

Comment: I can't say anything about this fact "why emulator is showing", But I will suggest you if you want to play animation then android gives you the solution in the form of animation(Search for android animations) also see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252153/setting-a-picture-as-a-background-for-an-activity-in-android), just a few minutes ago. It was a matter of the picture size.

Comment: my gif images are already of smaller size , say within 100 KB :( :(

Answer (score 1):

Dumb question but are the pics on the device? I know they should be in the apk but you never know. Ddms has a file explorer and you may need to do settings turn on usb they should be in data/data but maybe data sdcard or some vender specific location but you will find your project folder somewhere

Comment: well i dont consider it to be a dumb question at all , No i havent kept the images separately on the device , on the smartphone all i have is the apk installed , do you think i should keep the images on the device , if yes , then where

Comment: In order to see a picture it must be there, that is common sense. Now usually eclipse will take care of moving things for you. Different devices (real or virtual AKA AVD devices) have different screen sizes and this link explains http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html so as you can see if your AVD is one size and your smart phone another pictures will not display or not properly display. Android has multiple folders for different screen sizes so you can build an app that looks good on any device. Out of room I will continue...

Comment: Now your app is installed somewhere on the device so if you have some way to look at the files on the device, eclipse has a debugging tool called DDMS and part of DDMS is file explorer but you need to go into settings on the smart phone and enable usb debugging for it to work. Now where is the file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507960/does-android-keep-the-apk-files-if-so-where your application should be stored in data/data or maybe data/app depends on the vendor maybe even data/sdcard or something. when you find the app look for res/drawableXXX folder XXX is the screen size continued..

Comment: The picture should be in one of the res/drawable folders. If not use DDMS to move "push" pictures into the folder from your PC. One last comment from eclipse locate the res folder on the pc for your project. Right click on res and new/other/xml layout file. When you get to the "choose configuration folder" this is where you choose different screen sizes so your app will look good on any android device smartphone tablet... name it the same name as your other layout file and eclipse will make another layout for other sizes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (mMoviestart == 0) 
        {
            mMoviestart = now;
        }
        int gif_image_duration = mMovie.duration();
        if(gif_image_duration==0)
        {
            gif_image_duration = 1;
        }
        final int relTime = (int) ((now - mMoviestart) % gif_image_duration);
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);
        this.invalidate();
    }
```

Check this method all bugs lies in this method,
What is this for `canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`and that too you are calling it before `super.onDraw(canvas);` and also remove this `this.invalidate();` and check

You can use this method to load the images from assest folder

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Check these links too:

http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.in/2010/09/gif-animation-in-android.html

[Why are .gif animated images not animating in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760378/why-are-gif-animated-images-not-animating-in-my-android-app)

http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/

Comment: will check it and let you know

Comment: and also use PNGs instead of GIFs

Comment: the whole point is to use GIF , png i can in many ways , the point is to use animated gif images

Answer (score 0):

here is what I have done

step 1 : create a simple webview within my layout

step 2 : keep the gifs in assets folder

step 3 : use

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/","<html style=\"height:90%;width:95%\"><body>" +
                "<img src=\""+gif_char+".gif"+"\" " +
                "style=\"height:100%;width:100%\"></body></html>","text/html", "UTF-8","");
```

step 4 : keep the base location : `file:///android_asset/`

yeah and the gifs run like a charm

well i know this is not the explanation of the issue I had ,
but this is the alternate solution i did