# Setting a picture as a background for an activity in android

Tags: android, xml, background

I am Trying to set to set this picture `soccer_field` in `drawable` folder. When I view the "graphical layout" it is showing the background, but when I run it on my device it is not ..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/soccer_field"
android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

Why is this happening and how to solve it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference might be different screen resolutions between Emulator and your device. So maybe your device is looking in another drawable folder like drawable-xhdpi and it cannot find the drawable in their or in any other drawable folder suitable for the device resolution.

[Here you can find more about this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Comment: I tried to put my picture in all the drawable folders and it still not working !!

Comment: If it can't find it in the `drawable-??dpi` folder, it looks in `drawable` by default, which is where the OP says it is.

Comment: Well, difficult. The `soccer_field`  is a PNG file?  Do you do something with the layout in your code? Can you try and add some text view with dummy text to see, if anything is shown on your device?

Comment: @Geobits I think so too.  My guess was, that in the other folder another drawable with the same name was put (accidentally)

Comment: I tried to change the picture and it worked .. would it be because the picture i was trying previously had a size of 1.5 MB "the new one is just 51 KB" ?? ..

Comment: Good to see that it works now. At least the bitmap should take a while to be shown and depending on your device might be too much for the memory.